# Como resolver este error de buffer con 3 variables char en c++

Tags: c++, c, dev-c++, c++11, codeblocks

estoy aprendiendo a programar en c++ orientado a POO, tengo una clase llamada **Pedido** con sus **atributos** *(Nombre, Telefono, Direccion, Texto)*, los 4 atributos son del tipo de dato **char** y un **método** llamado *cargar* donde el usuario carga los atributos de la clase.
Una vez **instanciado** esa **clase**, se llama al **método** *cargar*, el usuario ingresa los datos, y se muestran, al mostrarse se produce el error con el buffer, quedando pegadas (por así decirlo), algunas cadenas de caracteres en otros metodos.

```
class Proveedor{

    private:

        char Nombre[50];
        char Telefono[10];
        char Direccion[50];
        char Texto[100];

    public:

        bool Cargar();
        void Mostrar();
};


bool Proveedor::Cargar(){

    cout<<"Ingrese el nombre: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(Nombre, 50, '\n');
    if(strlen(Nombre)<3){
        cout<<"No ingreso el nombre";
        return false;
    }

    cout<<"Ingrese el telefono: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(Telefono, 10, '\n');
    if(strlen(Telefono)<10){
        cout<<"No ingreso el telefono";
        return false;
    }

    cout<<"Ingrese el direccion: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(Direccion, 50, '\n');
    if(strlen(Direccion)<5){
        cout<<"No ingreso el telefono";
        return false;
    }

    cout<<"Ingrese la Descripcion: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(Texto, 100, '\n');

return true;
}


void Proveedor::Mostrar(){
    cout<<Nombre<<endl;
    cout<<Telefono<<endl;
    cout<<Direccion<<endl;
    cout<<Texto<<endl<<endl;
}
```

Muchas gracias a todos estaré esperando sus respuestas !!

Comment: Telefono tiene un tamaño para 10 caracteres. Eso son 9 para los numeros y uno para el `\0`. `cin.getline(Telefono, 10, '\n');` Va a leer 9 caracteres y va a insertar el `\0` al final, haciendo que `strlen(Telefono)<10` sea siempre falso.

Comment: Genial muchas gracias, ya funciona perfecto.!